# Creating aggregate attribute from two polygon layers

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, overlapping-features, aggregation, dynamic

I have two layers: one underlying land use information layer (with columns `"land_use_type"` and `"area"`) and one for leased land.

To organize the leasing of the land it would be important that when drawing a polygon for an area I want to lease to have columns which tell me how much area of the drawn polygon is covered by land-use type (e.g. wood, farmland etc..).

I tried a bit around with the aggregate function and a virtual field, but to no avail:

```
aggregate(
    layer:='Land_Use',
    aggregate:='sum',
    expression:="area",
    filter:=contains(geometry(@parent), $geometry),
    order_by:="land_use_type"
    )
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: no, unfortunately not. it is still "null"

Comment: the typo was just here (i had to translate the names from german..)

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

As a working solution I can suggest using a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`.

Let's assume there are two polygon layers called *'land_use_info'* (dark red) and *'leased_land'* (yellow).

[image: input]

With the following Query, it is possible to have columns which tell me how much area of the drawn polygon is covered by land-use type.

```sql
SELECT ll.*, GROUP_CONCAT(lui."land_type" || ':' || round(st_area(st_intersection(ll.geometry, lui.geometry)),4)) AS "info"
FROM "leased_land" AS ll
JOIN "land_use_info" AS lui ON st_intersects(ll.geometry, lui.geometry)
GROUP BY ll.id
```

The output polygon layer with its attribute table will look like

[image: result]

Comment: this goes perfectly in the right direction, i do not get an output for my data structure though.. i m looking into it, this looks very promising!

Comment: Check layers' names, are they specified in the right way? What does your output look like?

Comment: unfortunately no pic uploads possible in the answer section. i double checked the layer names ("lease" with colum "id" and some more, unrelevant ones and "Land_Use" with the column "LU_type"). My output virtual layer does not have the column "info". Both layers are in the same EPSG (intersect works with the QGIS onboard tool) and no features (althogh i have one feature in the "Lease" table - i will digg into it tomorrow, maybe it is because of the encoding of the files..or because of the "unrelevant" columns of my "Lease" table or..

Comment: Column `"info"` is created automatically, which is an attribute you require. Let's handle it today, should not be that difficult.